# Using groups in OpenRefine regex

Tags: openrefine

I'm wondering if it is possible to use "groups" in [ReGeX used in Open Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/UnderstandingRegularExpressions) GREL syntax. I mean, I'd like to replace all the dots followed and preceded by a character WITH the same character and dot but followed by a space and then the character.

Something like:

```
s.replace(/(.{1})\..({1})/,/(1).\s(2)/)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should, but your last argument needs to be a string, not a regular expression.  Internally Refine uses Java's [Matcher#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) method which accepts a string argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out how to deal with this. You need to put $X in your string value to address a Xth capture group.

It should be like this:

> s.replace(/.*?(#capcure group 1).*?(#capcure group 2).*?/), " some text $1 some text $2 some text")